# What have suppose to using laravel yield() function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

main page -> welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.footer_back_to_top')
@section('footer_back_to_top')

@endsection()
```

footer page -> footer_back_to_top.blade.php

```html
<p id="back-top">
    <a href="#top"><span></span> Back to Top</a>
</p>
@yield('footer_back_to_top')
```

The question I want to ask is without using @yield('footer_back_to_top') still will display the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, result won't be displayed. You should use `@yield` to make this section displayed and in child view you normally define `@section` where you define what should be displayed.